# One instance of "byte[]" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 29,393,296 (40.58%) bytes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, analyzer, eclipse-memory-analyzer

**why?**

> *how to solve?* `byte[]` *need to set* `null`?
>   Eclipse Memory Analyzer

[image]

Comment: Does your app use images?

Comment: my app uses images in a recyclerview and iam using xamarin. getting very similar output to this.? beeen using universal image loader and ive tried to be as optimal as possible with memory.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this question depends on code how have you used `byte[]` in your application.

How to get it resolved ?

- Check in your application where you are initializing arrays of `byte`
- Re-use array elements over itearation of loop
- Nullify array references when they are not in use

Check logcat messages with tag : `dalvikvm` and run your application. Check where

> **D/dalvikvm(28039): GC_CONCURRENT freed 473K, 7% free 9503K/10180K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 22ms**

Here, watch on fields -

1. **7%** free **9503K**/10180K  -

> **9503K** is amount which is holding live object references in our application. As you traverse inside your application, this value will
>   grow up. This is normal. BUT parallely GC is also running and trying
>   to free resources/object references which are not strongly connected.
>   If you do not find value **9503K** go down then this is warning to us.
>   This is signal that our application is certainly leaking memory.

For memory optimization in details, you should check [Google IO video for memory optimization and using mat tool of eclipse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)